# Tensor Algebra for Riemannian Geometry

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, tensors

I'm trying to learn a little bit about Riemannian geometry, but the books that I'm looking through seem to assume that the reader is familiar with topics such as contracting tensors, raising and lowering indices, trace, etc... I have had a bit of a hard time finding a source for learning these topics and still do not have a clue as to why such operations are useful. I was wondering if there is a short resource that goes over all the necessary tensor algebra to study Riemannian Geometry.

Comment: [Here's](https://www.goshen.edu/physix/mathphys/gco/TensorGuideAJP.pdf) a short document on tensors.  It's not my favorite piece on tensors but it's short.

Comment: Ah! Welcome to Riemannian geometry! All those tensor products, exterior algebras etc. are too hard for a first year course in linear algebra, but then when you take a grad course in geometry, the professor is like "oh, this is just linear algebra..." You never learn it... I had to go and grab all that stuff piece by piece. However, Warner's book *Foundations of Differential Manifolds and Lie Groups* can be quite helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature*. The second chapter contains a review of tensors (both on a vector space, and on a manifold) and discusses all of the topics you mentioned.

Comment: I should add this to my anwser, sorry about that. I am just selling books:-)